# How mongodb saves data to key value storage?

Tags: json, mongodb, key-value-store, rocksdb

I want to implement an application specific database and I need to save json like data. I chose rocksdb as storage but I don't know how to save a nested object like json to a key value storage.

For better design I need to know how mongodb saves documents in a key value storage...

It's so useful if someone explain mongodb indexing mechanism as well!

Best regards.

Comment: Go to https://university.mongodb.com/ and follow the training videos there.

Comment: MongoDB uses [BSON](https://bsonspec.org) and [WiredTiger](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M-Fi-pOG1ua)